# How to display array relation ManyToMany in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning symfony and making an project.
I have two entities User and Relation which have relation ManyToMany.

So I have table relation_user which have user_id and relation_id

I have this in MainController.php

```
 public function index(UserRepository $users,RelationRepository $relation)
{
    $user= $users->findAll();
    $relations =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Relation::class) ->findBy([],['id' => 'ASC']);
    return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'relations'=>$relations
    ]);
}
public function family(UserRepository $users, RelationRepository $relation, $id)
{
     $user = $users -> findAll();
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $relation = $entityManager->getRepository(Relation::class)->find($id);

    if($relation == null and $user ==null){
        return $this->redirectToRoute('main');
    }else{
    return $this->render('main/family.html.twig', [
        'relations' => $relation,
        'users' => $user,
    ]);
    }
}
```

I have this code in index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Family{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>Family</h1>
    {% for relation in relations %}
{% for users in user %}

<li><a href="{{ path('family',{'id':users.id}) }}">{{ users.firstname}} {{ users.partner }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Who display 2 lines:
user_id_1 with relation_id_1 and user_id_1 with relation_id_2

I would like to know how to have an array which contain user_id_1 with both relation_id

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to fetch all the relations in your controller to do that. Your User entity should implements the getRelations() method, which allows you to do this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    User id {{ user.id }} is in relation with:
    <br>

    {% for relation in user.relations %}
        {# here you are looping through all relations of a user so you can use both user.id and relation.id and others fields related to relation entity #}

        - {{ relation.id }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

So you can skip the $relations query in your controller:

```
// Not needed anymore:
$relations =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Relation::class) ->findBy([],['id' => 'ASC']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!